# AWS S3 displaying a file on the client browser

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to use AWS to store all files from my app there. I was successfully able to upload them to the bucket, but I am not able to retrieve the object to show it to the user. I am getting an error "You cannot call GetObject on the service resource." I am not sure what is wrong? I thought it was permission issues? but if so how come I can upload the file?

Here is what I have

```
function aws_file_upload($key,$file)
{

    $aws = aws();

    // Get a resource representing the S3 service.
    $s3 = $aws->s3;
    $bucket = $s3->bucket('my-bucket-name');

    try{
        $result = $object = $bucket->putObject([
            'Key'  => $key,
            'Body' => fopen($file, 'r'),
    ]);
    $status = 'OK';

    }catch(Exception $e){
        $status = 'error';
    }

    return $status;
}

function aws_file_get($key)
{
    $aws = aws();
    $s3 = $aws->s3;
    $result = $s3->getObject([
        'Bucket' => 'my-bucket-name',
        'Key'    => $key
    ]);

   // Display the object in the browser.
   header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
   echo $result['Body'];

}
$key = 'Cases/my-file.pdf';
$file_name = 'my-file.pdf';
$res = aws_file_upload($key,$file_name);/// this will put the file into the AWS bucket 

$result = aws_file_get($key);/// this will through the error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wanting an answer here was my solution.

```
$aws = aws();
$s3 = $aws->s3;
$bucket = $s3->bucket('my-bucket-name');

$result = $bucket->object($key)->get();

header("Content-Type: {$result['ContentType']}");
echo $result['Body'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an **s3 client**.

Here is some sample code from [Creating and Using Amazon S3 Buckets with the AWS SDK for PHP Version 3 - AWS SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-examples-creating-buckets.html):

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;  
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => '2006-03-01'
]);
$result = $s3Client->putObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key,
    'SourceFile' => $file_Path,
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I already have an s3 Client. $aws = aws(); $s3 = $aws->s3; I can put the object in the bucket. I can't retrieve it.